# actionscript: how to write a function to judge the input string contains only number and alphabet?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Only the number and alphabet is allowed to be contained in the input string, return true or false.

function is_valid(str:String):Boolean {
}

My implementation is dumb, as I want to iterate each character.

Input: akjd8899kdjfj2kj return: true
Input: kjd^kdjf^%%$ return: false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with a regular expression:

```
function isValid(value:String):Boolean
{
   var result:String = value.match(/[0-9a-zA-Z]*/)[0];

   return value.length == result.length;
}
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that that regular expression will only allow numbers and the English alphabet, not characters like ñ, ü or ö.